# How do I add more words to an existing Aspell dictionary?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, r, aspell

I have installed Aspell dictionary to spell check my document. But in the document there are some words which are spelled incorrectly but I do not want Aspell to detect those as incorrect. So, basically I want to add those words to the existing Aspell dictionary.

I am trying to follow instructions given here: http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Adding_words_to_existing_aspell_dictionaries but I am not able to understand the commands given here and also where to type these commands. I tried executing these commands on command prompt but I keep getting errors regarding directory. This is what I am trying on command prompt.

My Aspell program's path is C:/Program Files (x86)/Aspell/

```
C:\Program Files (x86)>/Aspell/bin/./aspell --lang=en create master yourl
ist.rws < C:/Users/admin/Desktop/yourlist.txt
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Program Files (x86)>
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong? I have not worked before on command prompt.

Also if there is any other easier alternative (like doing so form R GUI) please suggest that too.

Comment: the above instruction are not for windows ti for linux i will try find the windows version for oyu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764635/aspell-dictionary-cant-be-opened this one describe how it done you need to create a few files